# combine unicode characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode

i am able to split unicode characters using this

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "कसौटी";
    var res = str.split("");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

however it splits all the characters like this

`क,स,ौ,ट,ी`

how can i merge `स,ौ` to get सौ

and `ट,ी` to get टी

the problem is i want to split the characters first then rejoin it, these are conjuncts in Hindi and need to be presented that way

Comment: Can't you just put them next to each other?

Comment: Is there a finite list of conjuncts? Can you create a look-up table for all the first characters that might appear in a conjunct, and iterate through it, looking for matches? (Is this list comprehensive? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Hindi/Consonant_combinations)

Comment: Is this helpful? http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html

Comment: yes thats exactly what i was thinking , but i am just stuck at how to combine the unicode characters javascript is totally new to me, i can make different combinations if only i would know how to combine them

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dictionary of unicode for the hindi characters, here is a link for [full table](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf) and here is how you do it in code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
     var theDictionary = {'\u0bbf':true,'\u0bcd':true,...}; //example of unicode, add yours
     var temporaryList ="कसौटी".split('');
    var targetList = [];
    for(var index in temporaryList ){
      if(theDictionary [temporaryList [index]])
      {
        targetList[targetList.length - 1] +=  temporaryList [index];
      }
      else
      {
        targetList.push(temporaryList [index]);
      }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Remember, you **must** create the dictionary or it won't work, becuase without it the hindi string won't be recognized.

Comment: i tried to use your code but i am totally new to javascript how can i use it in this code **  <button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "कसौटी";
    var res = str.split("");
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>**

Comment: hey i editied the answer, please tell me if it worked or there is another part in the puzzle need to be completed.

Comment: thanks for your help, it does not show any output, even if one of the words is shown as i have mentioned above i can try further , could you help with this a bit, can try it on jsfiddle . i am trying to work with this  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp and here is the code i am trying http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_split3